# Dont let google crawl my sites

Tags: drupal, seo

Is there a way to hide my drupal site from the googlebots? I don't want my site to show up in the search engines while it's still in the development stage.

Comment: i am currently using .htpasswd , i wonder if it does the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use robots.txt such as :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: <directory you want to hide>
```

You can allow searching of some directories if you wish or none at all using 
Disallow: /

More info at robotstxt.org :-)

Dave

Comment: and if the OP wanted to disallow Googlebot specifically, a User-agent of: Googlebot could be used (per http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449 )

Answer (score 9):

Use [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

Answer (score 6):

Use [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) to block search engines...

But!

You need to consider developing your site away from the real domain.  When you go live, how are you going to develop enhancements to your site?  You need a development environment now.

Additionally you could be building your inbound links and search engine ranking before you put your site live.  Preventing your site being indexed by Google until you go live will stop this happening.

I would suggest putting a landing page on your main domain, with messaging that reflects the purpose of your site, and the ability to perhaps 'register interest' with the site.  This will allow you to get your domain name out there.

Launching a new website will almost always happen with thunderous silence.  Getting your domain ranked before launch is a highly worthwhile activity.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file containing the following in the base directory of your webserver called robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option is to put something like this in you `.htaccess`

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From all
Allow From 1.2.3.4
```

and just use your IP address, or multiple IP addresses if there are multiple remote locations working on the site.

But I do second the comment about developing off of the main domain.  Get a VPS account, put up a splash site on the main domain using a virtual host, and create a subdomain and virtual host for it (and protect it like shown above), and use that for development.

Answer (score 0):

Require a login. I don't think the Google bot will log in...